# How to redirect a search term to a new page after a "?" is entered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, search

I am building an engine with search and was wandering a way to have it redirect my query to an answer page once the user hits the "?" key.

E.G.

1. User types in query. What is 4 + 4
2. Follows up with a "?".
3. Transition appears, then is redirected to new page with question and answer on it.

Here is my code that I have so far:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search"></form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I'm unsure whether CSS, JS or another coding skill would work best with what I'm trying to acheive. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: JS ... Have a look at that first before asking here...

Answer (score 4):

you can have an event listener to your input field and on every key up check the value of key. if the key is the one you are looking for e.g. '?' then grab the data of that input field and do further processing.

I'd suggest you give some id for your input field so that it will be unique and you can access it easily.

```js
var field = document.getElementById('search');

field.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  var searchText = this.value;
  if(searchText.indexOf('?') > -1){//Means there is ?
    var textToProcess = searchText;
    //do anything you want with this
  }

})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" name="search">
```

if you want event listener on name instead on id, then

```
var field = document.getElementsByName('search')[0];
```

since getElementsByName will return collection of elements, youll have to manually give the index of field (in case you have more then one field with same name else [0] will do)

Comment: I changed the code to look like this. I think that I need an action for the redirect but I don't know how to do this.:
       var field = document.getElementById('search');
     
       field.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
     var searchText = this.value;
      if(searchText.indexOf('?') > -1){//Means there is ?
        var textToProcess = searchText;
        $(location).attr('href', 'answer.html')
      }
     
    })

Comment: okay, for that you can use `window.location="yourfile.html"` and if you want to pass parameters you can use "?" after the url and send it. e.g `window.location = 'yournewfile.html?question='+textToProcess`

Comment: For me, it doesn't redirect to a new page on keypress. And, the debugger says "null is not an object, (evaluating 'field.addEventListener') for the third line of code      field.addEventListener('keyup', function() {